# How to use hibernate-search with JBoss datagrid?

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss, hibernate-search

I have this requirement to use JBoss Datagrid to stop some document and make it searchable. So, I'm thinking of using Hibernate-search which is part of JBoss already. But now I'm stuck. Here's a simple code I produced in JUnit.

```
@Test
public void testName() throws Exception {
    Cache<Object, Object> c = new DefaultCacheManager().getCache();
    c.put("id", new ProductDG("ean", "desc", newArrayList("image1")));

    ProductDG product = (ProductDG) c.get("id");
    assertTrue(product.getEAN().equals("ean"));

    SessionFactory factory = new AnnotationConfiguration().buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = factory.openSession();

    FullTextSession fts = getFullTextSession(session);
    fts.index(product);

}


@Indexed(index="Product")
class ProductDG {
    private String EAN;
    private String description;

    private List<String> images;

    ProductDG(String EAN, String description, List<String> images) {
        this.EAN = EAN;
        this.description = description;
        this.images = images;
    }

    String getEAN() {
        return EAN;
    }

    String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    List<String> getImages() {
        return images;
    }
}
```

But I got error like this.

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Connection cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:174)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:159)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1797)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1755)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1840)
    at com.tesco.adapters.JBossDataGrid.testName(JBossDataGrid.java:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:77)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:195)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

which I'm thinking I don't have Database to connect to. How would this work at all? I was told that I have to use JBoss Datagrid. I'm aware of https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/ogm/3.0/reference/en-US/html_single/ but it's too new and it has just come out a few months ago. Can this be done at all?

Answer (score 0):

You're correct that JBoss Data Grid uses Hibernate Search, but it only does for indexing and query definition: you don't need to use it via the "traditional" Hibernate Session.

- You don't need to start an Hibernate SessionFactory
- You don't even need the Hibernate ORM jars on your classpath
- You do use annotations from Hibernate Search

To make an example inspired by your domain, to use it you only need to enable indexing in the [configuration of the Cache](http://infinispan.org/docs/6.0.x/user_guide/user_guide.html#_configuration_7).

```
@Test
public void testName() throws Exception {
   Cache<Object, Object> c = new DefaultCacheManager("configuration-file.xml").getCache();
   c.put("id", new ProductDG("ean", "desc", newArrayList("image1")));
   //at this point your Product is already indexed (assuming you don't use transactions)

   //Using the MatchAllDocsQuery we'll get a list of all instances:
   CacheQuery query = searchManager.getQuery(new MatchAllDocsQuery(), ProductDG.class);

   // Execute Query
   List objectList = query.list();

   for (Object prod : objectList)
      System.out.println(prod);

}
```

Your last question is about Hibernate OGM. Yes that can be done as well, but you probably want to read the documentation for version 4:

> https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/ogm/4.0/reference/en-US/html_single/